# start a timer from different thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, timer

Hi i have stepped into some problem related to timer.
hope somebody can help..

1. I have a windows form containing a button
2. when i click on that button i start a parameterised thread

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart( execute2));
thread1.Start(externalFileParams);
```

1. the code inside the thread executes very well
2. at the last line of this thread i start a timer

.

```
public void execute2(Object ob)
{
    if (ob is ExternalFileParams)
    {
        if (boolean_variable== true)
          executeMyMethod();//this also executes very well if condition is true
        else
        {
            timer1.enabled = true;
            timer1.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5 but the tick event of the timer is not fired

I am working on VS2008 3.5 framework. I have dragged the timer from toolbox and set its `Interval` to 300 also tried to set `Enabled` true/false
method is `timer1_Tick(Object sender , EventArgs e)` but its not fired

can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's most unlikely that this is the best way to achieve what you want - if you have a long-running task that needs to update a form with progress, then BackgroundWorker is a good way to do it.  If you need more manual control, then a pool thread (look at ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem) is better than creating your own thread.

Comment: you would need to invoke the timer.start on the thread of its host form/control but it is an awkward way of doing it. Use `Control.BeginInvoke` to call an appropriate delegate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try to start the timer this way:

Add in form constructor this:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
 // Set the Interval to 1 second.
 aTimer.Interval = 1000;
```

Add this method to Form1:

```
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
   //do something with the timer
 }
```

On button click event add this:

```
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

This timer is already threaded so no need to start a new thread.

Answer (score 8):

It is true what Matías Fidemraizer says. But, there is a work around...

When you have a control on your form that is invokable (eg. a statusbar), just invoke that one!

C# Code sample:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread sampleThread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        // Invoke your control like this
        this.statusStrip1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }));
    });
    sampleThread.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I just ticked!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

System.Windows.Forms.Timer works in a single-threaded application.

Check this link:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Remarks says:

> A Timer is used to raise an event at
>   user-defined intervals. This Windows
>   timer is designed for a
>   single-threaded environment where UI
>   threads are used to perform
>   processing. It requires that the user
>   code have a UI message pump available
>   and always operate from the same
>   thread, or marshal the call onto
>   another thread.

Read more "Remarks" section and you'll find that Microsoft recommends that you use this timer synchronizing it with the UI thread.

Comment: Haha, read my last sentence (it was there for an hour!!) :) Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) (instead of a *raw* thread). The main thread would subscribe to the worker's [RunWorkerCompleted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx): The event fires in your main thread when the thread completes. Use this event handler to restart your timer.