# Timer tick event in separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

Is it anyone how to create a thread for timer tick event.
In Windows desktop application timer tick event should
be controlled by a separate thread.
Is it possible?

Comment: there is a selection of timers to suit your needs, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx should help you choose

Comment: possible duplicate of [start a timer from different thread in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727023/start-a-timer-from-different-thread-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and the timer event will fire on a worker thread.

> The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

I am assuming that what you mean by "should be controlled by a separate thread" is that the event handler runs on a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: Obviously I'm asking about that only